# QUERY_STRING exact match

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How do I make exact match for a partial URL, like:

```
page_id=11
```

301 to xyz.com
but `page_id=118` remains `page_id=118`

I have now 
`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page_id=11` but it works for 118 and anything with 11 in it too.

Comment: Please ask over in http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this condition:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)page_id=11(&|$) [NC]
```